# Use PowerShell Add Web Browser Control, Prompt Script Error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a web browser control using powershell, but I am experiencing the following problem, any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance

1.Some simple web pages can be displayed normally

2.But for html5 web pages, or web pages with flash controls, they can't load properly, showing script errors.

3.If I use IE browser to open the above three pages directly, I can open them successfully.

The following GIF image shows the loading of three web pages

[image]

```
function Show-web_psf {

    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    #endregion Import Assemblies

    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
    $webbrowser1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser'
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'

    $form1_Load = {
        #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here

    }

    function Set-WebBrowserEmulation
    {
        param
        (
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [string]$ExecutableName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
        )

        #region Get IE Version
        $valueNames = 'svcVersion', 'svcUpdateVersion', 'Version', 'W2kVersion'

        $version = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $valueNames.Length; $i++)
        {
            $objVal = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::GetValue('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer', $valueNames[$i], '0')
            $strVal = [System.Convert]::ToString($objVal)
            if ($strVal)
            {
                $iPos = $strVal.IndexOf('.')
                if ($iPos -gt 0)
                {
                    $strVal = $strVal.Substring(0, $iPos)
                }

                $res = 0;
                if ([int]::TryParse($strVal, [ref]$res))
                {
                    $version = [Math]::Max($version, $res)
                }
            }
        }

        if ($version -lt 7)
        {
            $version = 7000
        }
        else
        {
            $version = $version * 1000
        }
        #endregion

        [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION', $ExecutableName, $version)
    }

    #endregion

    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm_Click = {
        #TODO: Place custom script here
        $webbrowser1.Url = "http://www.bing.com"
    }

    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro_Click = {
        #TODO: Place custom script here
        $webbrowser1.Url = "http://online.focusky.com/fazc/plom/"
    }

    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen_Click = {
        #TODO: Place custom script here
        $webbrowser1.Url = "http://fs.focusky.com.cn/gtsdr/nelz/index.html?flash"
    }

    #region Generated Events
    #----------------------------------------------

    $Form_StateCorrection_Load=
    {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    $Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
    {
        #Remove all event handlers from the controls
        try
        {
            $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.remove_Click($buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen_Click)
            $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.remove_Click($buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro_Click)
            $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.remove_Click($buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm_Click)
            $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
            $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
            $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
        }
        catch { Out-Null <# Prevent PSScriptAnalyzer warning #> }
    }
    #endregion Generated Events

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    #----------------------------------------------
    $form1.SuspendLayout()
    #
    # form1
    #
    $form1.Controls.Add($webbrowser1)
    $form1.Controls.Add($buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen)
    $form1.Controls.Add($buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro)
    $form1.Controls.Add($buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm)
    $form1.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
    $form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
    $form1.ClientSize = '944, 502'
    $form1.Name = 'form1'
    $form1.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $form1.Text = 'Form'
    $form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
    #
    # webbrowser1
    #
    $webbrowser1.Anchor = 'Top, Bottom, Left, Right'
    $webbrowser1.Location = '-3, 42'
    $webbrowser1.MinimumSize = '20, 20'
    $webbrowser1.Name = 'webbrowser1'
    $webbrowser1.Size = '945, 460'
    $webbrowser1.TabIndex = 3
    #
    # buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen
    #
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.Location = '613, 13'
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.Name = 'buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen'
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.Size = '298, 23'
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.TabIndex = 2
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.Text = 'Flash Web: Unable to open, prompt script error'
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen.add_Click($buttonFlashWebUnableToOpen_Click)
    #
    # buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro
    #
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.Location = '292, 13'
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.Name = 'buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro'
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.Size = '297, 23'
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.TabIndex = 1
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.Text = 'H5 Web: Unable to open, prompt script error'
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro.add_Click($buttonH5WebUnableToOpenPro_Click)
    #
    # buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm
    #
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.Location = '33, 13'
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.Name = 'buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm'
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.Size = '235, 23'
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.TabIndex = 0
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.Text = 'Simple web: Can open normally'
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm.add_Click($buttonSimpleWebCanOpenNorm_Click)
    $form1.ResumeLayout()
    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #----------------------------------------------

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
    #Clean up the control events
    $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    #Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

#Call the form
Show-web_psf | Out-Null
```

Comment: Have you enabled javascript in Internet Option ?

Comment: @Niraj Gajjar With IE, I can open the above three pages successfully !!!